# How can i tag the annotation in the map and get the tag value while selecting the annotation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Iam doing a project for deliver food online through map. so the user should know the cook location. When the user tap on the annotation, it should view the food menus of the cook. so when user tap i need to call the cooks id. I can can call the cooks id according to the tag value.

```
**Juntos.swift**


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> 
MKAnnotationView?
{
    var annotationView = 
mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier")

    if annotationView == nil
      {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, 
         reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
      }
    else
      {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
      }

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else
      {
        return nil
      }

    if iamA == "COOK"
      {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "foodie")
      }
    else
      {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "cook")
      }
           return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    //    how can i get annotation tag here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set tag here like this-

```
annotationView.tag = 1
return annotationView
```

And get tag like this-

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    // get annotation tag here
       let tag = view.tag
}
```

Comment: id not put data into a VIEW id -- it somehow 'hides' the fact that it is UI unrelated data (but thats opinionated a bit)

Comment: But there is a problem. I have multiple annotations so i give the tag value as from the string variable, but all the annotations are setting its tag as the last value of the string.

Comment: Tag should be int value not string value.

Comment: Yeah it is an Int value not string

Answer (score 6):

subclass MKAnnoation and enable it to hold custom data... e.g. the id:

```
class MyAnnotation: MKAnnotation {
    var identifier: String!
}
```

now add that instead of MKAnnotation

```
let a = MyAnnotation()
....
a.identifier = "id525325"
mapView.addAnnotation(a)
```

and in then later use it

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let a = view.annoation as? MyAnnoation else {
        return
    }
    let identifier = a.identifier
```

Comment: Actually the annotation is showing on the map view according to the latitude and longitude values. now i need to pass the array string at indexpath corresponding to the annotation tag.. for example. i have an array.

Comment: let myArray = ["q" , "w" , "e"]

Comment: The annotation is you dataovject and next to coordinate can take EVERYTHING

Comment: if i tap on the annotation which is having the tag value of 2 should pass the value myArray[2], which is "e"

Comment: Save a string array instead of a string in your case

Comment: a.identifier = array[2] Or array[a.identifier]. 2. Option is not good